# Get offset and scroll to specific position in Expandable listview android

Tags: android, scroll, textview, expandablelistview, offset

I have a ExpandableListView with large text in child TextViews.
I need functionality to search for a string which returns a vertical offset of that point so that i can use `smoothScrollBy(offset,duration)` method to move to specified position.

I'm computing `OnScrollListener` for my listview which provides current offset which can be saved for further use, however i'm struck when i need to calculate offset based on matching a string within text. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide us some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'll provide that as soon as i get back to my workspace. For the time being the concept that i've implemented is calculating total offset upto current position with every scroll in my Expandable listview.